# Intercept IIS Windows Authentication via HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, httpmodule

As we know, for NTLM, there are two 401 http response and then a 200 http response is followed. Just wonder if there is anyway we could step in to modify the http response header for those 401 http responses especially the second 401 http response.  did quite some search over the internet and I haven't found any related information. [HttpModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) is usually the approach to intercept every request, however from this link [.NET HttpModule & NTLM Integrated Authentication](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/net-httpmodule-ntlm-integrated-authentication.71415/), it has the following wording at one of replies:

> What you want to do is not possible with .Net HttpModule. Authentication
>   has already been done by IIS by the time an HttpModule gets control.

We confirmed this at our testing as well. It seems that our HttpModule won't get called during 401 request/response ( technically for us, it is only second 401, since for the first 401, 401 is set by our code and then returned to client browser. The reason why we are doing so is that we need to have one login page to support multiple authentication methods based on end user's selection and we could get into details about this if required).

The reason why I am asking this is that vulnerability scan software of one of our customers has marked the second 401 http response as a vulnerability issue due to that there is no header like "cache-control: no-cache". We are able to add such header by using a http module for every requests passing through our code, but not the second 401 request/response. Any insights? Thanks very much.

Comment: I tried to add cache-control header at IIS web site. Now other responses which already have cache-control header would get some duplicate values, however this second 401 response still doesn't  have the cache-control header. I guess IIS won't pass through even its own custom header processing for this authentication process.